# R - How to search for a string in an array of strings

Tags: r, string

I have a table like below:

```
X   Y
a   kite
b   kiterunner
c   skite
d   sklite
e   skiter
f   runner
```

Now, I need to search for kite and for each row I find it, I need to add a Z column with "Yay", otherwise "Nay". Basically the following is to be the output:

```
X   Y           Z
a   kite        Yay
b   kiterunner  Yay
c   skite       Yay
d   sklite      Nay
e   skiter      Yay
f   runner      Nay
```

I tried `grep`, but it searches the whole column put all "Yay"s. I think I am missing some basic stuff here, but can't really figure it out... Didn't sleep for almost 24 hours. Please help.

My code now:

```
Table$Z <- ifelse(grep("kite", Table$Y), "Yay", "Nay")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `grepl` in place of `grep`:

```
Table$Z <- ifelse(grepl("kite", Table$Y), "Yay", "Nay")
```

Result:

```
> Table
  X          Y   Z
1 a       kite Yay
2 b kiterunner Yay
3 c      skite Yay
4 d     sklite Nay
5 e     skiter Yay
6 f     runner Nay
```

Or suggestion lmo:

```
c("Yay", "Nay")[grepl("kite", Table$Y) + 1L]
```

Answer (score 1):

We can do this without any `ifelse`

```
df1$Z <- with(df1, c("Nay", "Yay")[grepl("kite", Y)+1])
df1$Z
#[1] "Yay" "Yay" "Yay" "Nay" "Yay" "Nay"
```